# asp:SqlDataSource binded to asp:DropDownList

Tags: c#, sqldatasource

I have a asp:SqlDataSource and asp:DropDownList components on my page. On normal page it works ok.

Now I'd like to put this on new page with url like ...mypage.aspx?transactionID=2. In Page_Load I would like to set Transaction drop down selected index to 2. But it always binds to 1. I assume, that things happen in this order: in Page_Load I set selected index to 2. Then asp:SqlDataSource's select statement executes and binds to DropDownList. That's why selected index of my DropDownList is always 1, no matter what I set it in Page_Load.

So, how can I bind asp:SqlDataSource to asp:DropDownList and also set it's selected index parameter to some integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write an event handler for the DropDownLists's OnDataBound event to set the selected index *after* it's bound.